# Detecting combination of letters in string in php

Tags: php, string, search, substring

I have a certain not to short sting that are actually collection of flags/parameters (generated from a loop of products, but it does not matter).

Say:

```
aaaaaaaoooooreioopppdffdssds
yxxxsasadddddaaaaddaadadadad
oppppppassaaaaawwwwwww
```

And so on.

I need to detect if inside this longer string there is combination of certain flags.

For example:

```
aaaaa (5* letter a)
xyy (1*x + 2*y)
opp (1*o + 2*pp)
```

Basically if the longer sting contains 5 letters "a" then statement should be as true. It would be really easy if the was only situation like this `yyyyaaaaaaxxxx` (contains substring `aaaaa`). But the thing is that 5 "a" letters can be completely disconnected from each other like `yayaxayataya` (and it's just one example. There can be very many required flags combinations).

My guess is preg_match could do it - could someone tell me how?

Comment: So rather than finding "combinations", this could be rephrased as you need to look for a certain _count_ of occurrences of a specific letter? Regex on its own isn't all that suitable to do this job - but if you replace anything that is _not_ an `a` using regex, and then check the lenght of the resulting string afterwards ...?

Comment: Yest it could be phrased like that BUT replacing everything that is no `a` will only do the job for searching 5*a occurences. It would not do for `xyy` or `opp` (or any other combination, because this is change in the future, tomorrow it can be artufxkwuzjzuy) and I need a function that will return true/false.

Comment: So `aaaaa` means the string must contain 5 `a`s? But what does `xyy` mean? The string must contains 1 `x` and 2 `y`s? Is the order important?

Comment: Order not important `xyy` means that longer string must contain one letter `x` and 2 letters `yy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need this in an environment where you can *only* use regex - then I would go with

```
array_count_values(mb_str_split('aaaaaaaoooooreioopppdffdssds'));
```

That will give you the count for each character (multibyte-safe), so all you have to do now is check in the resulting array, if there is an entry for that character you are looking for, and if that count is equal to (or higher, if that is not to be excluded) the one you are looking for.

And if `xyy` is your "input" for which characters you need to find - then apply the same two functions to that as well, then you get an array that *gives* you the (minimum) counts you need to look for, so you can simply loop over that to perform your test.

```
function checkLetters($letters, $teststring) {
    $inputLetterCounts = array_count_values(mb_str_split($letters));
    $letterCounts = array_count_values(mb_str_split($teststring));
    foreach($inputLetterCounts as $inputLetter => $count) {
        if(!isset($letterCounts[$inputLetter]) ||
           $letterCounts[$inputLetter] < $count) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
var_dump(
    checkLetters('xxy', 'aaaaaaoooooreioopppdffdssds'), // false
    checkLetters('xxy', 'aaaaxaaoyooorexoopppdffdssds'), // true
);
```

Whether you want to check the count for `<` or `!=`, you decide - depends on whether you want to allow *more* occurrences of a character, or only that specific number.

Comment: Thanx. Unfortunately mb_str_split is a php7 function and I'm confined to php5 :/ on the working server - I will look for workaround for this.

Comment: @baron_bartek Just use `str_split` instead. It is highly unlikely that you will be using multi-byte charcters as flags for product related stuff.